# Javascript checking if two let variables are null or empty

Tags: javascript, html, href

I'm trying to send an email using the html form. I'm having a problem when trying to check if two let variables are null, because even beign these variables empty, it always sends an email.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.querySelector("#send_message_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let email_subject = document.querySelector("#subject").value;
      let email_body = document.querySelector("#text").value;
      let email_to = "example@gmail.com";
      if (!email_subject && !email_body)
      {
        location.href = 'mailto:'+email_to+'?subject='+email_subject+'&body='+email_body;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You have your logic inverted. You are sending the mail if both values are falsy (`null`/`undefined`/empty string, etc) instead of truthy. Use `email_subject && email_body`.

Comment: add your HTML form and put all code in a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your logic inverted, You need to replace

`!email_subject && !email_body` with `email_subject && email_body`

but you should also check for `whitespaces` by using the `trim()` method.

```
function isEmpty(value) {
    return (value == null || value.trim().length === 0);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.querySelector("#send_message_button").addEventListener("click", function () {
        let email_subject = document.querySelector("#subject").value;
        let email_body = document.querySelector("#text").value;
        let email_to = "example@gmail.com";
        if (isEmpty(email_subject) || isEmpty(email_body)) return;

        location.href = 'mailto:' + email_to + '?subject=' + email_subject + '&body=' + email_body;
    });
});
```